# Writing XML Exactly as XML Literals are Written

Tags: xaml, linq-to-xml, whitespace, xml-literals

I'm transforming some XML from DrawingML to XAML. Unfortunately, the XAML one is not working as expected with white spaces, but I have found a work around. Here's the problem:

### Problem Statment

I want to write the following in a TextBlock:

> Hi **John**, *what did Sushi A say to
>   Sushi B?*

So I would write:

```
<TextBlock>
 <Run>Hey</Run>
 <Run FontWeight="Bold">John</Run>
 <Run>,</Run>
 <Run FontStyle="Italic">what did Sushi A say to Sushi B?</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

This doesn't produce the desired results. Instead, it produces:

> Hi **John** , *what did Sushi A say to
>   Sushi B?*

Notice the space now between "`John`" and "`,`"? Weird, eh? This is because XAML appends a space between runs. I don't know why it does this. I really do need the formatting exactly as above, so the option of changing formatting, like making the comma bold too is not an option.

### Partial Solution

The weirder thing is that there is a way around this - i.e. to lose the extra space that XAML adds - you have to put your runs on the same line. I have no idea why, but that's the case. So the following actually works just fine:

```
<TextBlock>
 <Run>Hey</Run>
 <Run FontWeight="Bold">John</Run><Run>,</Run>
 <Run FontStyle="Italic">what did Sushi A say to Sushi B?</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Notice runs #2 and #3 (of 4 runs) are now on the same line.

### Question

The issue I'm having is that I haven't found a way to write the above using XML Literals. If I try this:

```
Dim tb = <TextBlock>
             <Run>Hey</Run>
             <Run FontWeight="Bold">John</Run><Run>,</Run>
             <Run FontStyle="Italic">what did Sushi A say to Sushi B?</Run>
         </TextBlock>
```

it is *always* created as the below, with the 4 runs on seperate lines:

```
<TextBlock>
 <Run>Hey</Run>
 <Run FontWeight="Bold">John</Run>
 <Run>,</Run>
 <Run FontStyle="Italic">what did Sushi A say to Sushi B?</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

***Does anyone know how XML can be written exactly as written in XML Literals?***

#### Bonus

If you answer the question correctly, I'll tell you the punchline of the joke :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance the unicode backspace character would solve your problem?

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0008/index.htm

**Update**

One other idea. Have you looked into the `XDocument.Save(TextWriter textWriter, SaveOptions saveOptions)` method? [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538297.aspx) says that if you use `SaveOptions.DisableFormatting`, it will preserve spacing.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't appear to have any effect as the backspace character just simply shows as a plain text.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I tried this and it kind of works. The main issue is how XAML is read by WPF/SL - it doesn't preserve spacing despite the Linq documentation. So in the case of this and tyranid's suggestion of leaving whitespaces within tags, like <Run> , <Run>, XAML will still not display those whitespaces. I may be able to get around that using something more like <Run Text=" , "/>. I'll let this thread fester for a day or two to see if some other ideas come in that are different than file format saves. That may be the only option though I realize.

Answer (score 2):

I don't suppose using a span will help you (as it will keep non-formatted text out of XML elements so it might not get auto-formatted).

i.e.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Span>                
        Hey
        <Bold>John</Bold>, 
        <Italic>what did Sushi A say to Sushi B?</Italic>
    </Span>            
</TextBlock>
```

Obviously this only fixes the specific case not the general, I would probably suggest not using XML literals :)

Comment: thanks, this does indeed work for the exact scenario. however, i do need to use runs for some of the properties they hold (like Foreground and Fontsize. +1 for a good suggestion though.

On not using XML Literals, I'd also be happy with just plain ol' Linq-to-XML (Dim tb as New XElement("TextBlock", content), etc.) if there is a way to do that in place of literals.

Comment: How exactly are you passing the XElement into XAML? If you are just passing it to XElement::ToString then there _is_ an option to disable output formatting. Do `tb.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)` You will need to ensure any white space you actually want is in the runs (i.e. <run>, </run>)

Which is pretty much the same as below :)

Comment: Yeah, I was testing this per Dan's suggestion. It kind of works.